# Do we use $p=ρgh$ to calculate the pressure caused by any materials or just by liquids?

Tags: pressure, fluid-statics, density

[image]

If instead of a liquid in those shapes the shape was a rigid body made up of iron or any other thing, Can I still use the same ration $p=ρgh$ to calculate pressure at some height $h$?

Comment: The phase of matter doesn't affect the result, but if $g$ varies throughout the height, as with atmospheric pressure, you need $dp=\rho gdh$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pressure is only useful in a static fluid. By definition a fluid is a substance  that does not support shear stress.

Inside a rigid body, such as a block of iron,  pressure is replaced by the more complicated  [stress tensor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_stress_tensor)

Comment: And the pressure at the bottom of those shapes above is different…

Comment: So, what you're saying is that I can't use p=ρgh to calculate the pressure with solids, Is that what you're saying?

Comment: Yes. Exactly. The forces in a solid are complicated, anisotropic,  and do not obey Pascal's law.

Answer (score -3):

any material, with one rule.
When in any formula you use $V$ as $A . h$ you must keep in mind that the object is a Prism(geometrical shape that has equal top and bottom base), which in this case, fluids have this property.
Another thing, $P = \frac{F}{A}$ so, $P = \frac{F . d}{A . d}$ thus, $P = \frac{W}{V} = \frac{Energy}{Volume}$ and therefore we assume pressure as energy a fluid has(Any kind of energy), and since we want the pressure of a static(stationary)(so it only has potential energy) liquid then we have $U = m.g.h$ and $P = \frac{U}{V} = \frac{m.g.h}{V} = \rho.g.h$

Comment: you can use this formula for prism-like objects if you have $\rho$, $g$, and $h$